# AngularJS $rootScope:infdig and ngRepeat:dupes

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have given up trying to figure this out and have scoured Google for help. From what I've gathered AngularJs works some kind of magic on variables and functions. Ive read that, despite you programming normally in Javascript, AngularJS is overly extremely finicky with functions and one tiny thing wrong crashes your program or possibly the browser in an infinite loop of errors. Something about functions and the way they handle data causes a new object to be created which doesnt matchup with AngularJS's magic backend's copy of the old data or something like that.

What I'm trying to do I really need AngularJS, and all I'm trying to do is get a list of items via ajax, insert it into a list, then inside each list item insert a second sub-list of items grabbed via ajax that is different based on the item its inserted into. I've been trying for 4 days now to get this to work.

I've rewritten the way all the functions themselves are declared, all the variables are declared, and the way all data is handled by the functions and variable dozens and dozens of times over.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" ng-app='app'> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" ng-app='app'> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" ng-app='app'> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" ng-app='app'> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="client_components/custom_component/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="client_components/custom_component/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="client_components/custom_component/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="client_components/custom_component/css/main.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="MasterCtrl">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        {{msg}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul class="list-group section-list" id="list">
                            <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="section in sections" ng-controller="SectionCtrl">
                {{section.sectionName}}&nbsp;
                                {{loadBranches(section.sectionName)}}

                                <ul class="list-group branch-list">
                                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" ng-repeat="branch in branches" ng-controller="BranchCtrl">
                                        {{branch.rawLine}}&nbsp;
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Unused
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Javascript Dependencies -->
    <!-- Modernizr and its Respond -->
    <script src="client_components/custom_component/js/vendor/modernizr-2.7.2.js" defer></script>
    <script src="client_components/custom_component/js/vendor/respond.js" defer></script>

    <!-- jQuery suite -->
    <script src="client_components/custom_component/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="client_components/custom_component/js/vendor/jcanvas.js" defer></script>
    <script src="client_components/custom_component/js/vendor/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js" defer></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap and Angular -->
    <script src="client_components/custom_component/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="client_components/custom_component/js/vendor/angular.min.js" defer></script>

    <!-- Custom -->
    <script src="client_components/custom_component/js/main.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And heres the Javascript Code

```
"use strict";

var appModule = angular.module('app', []);

 appModule.service("confService", function($http, $q)
 {
    // Expose Public API
    return({
        moveLine: moveLine,
        getAllLines: getAllLines,
        getAllLinesGroupedObj: getAllLinesGroupedObj,
        getAllLinesGroupedArr: getAllLinesGroupedArr,

        createSection: createSection,
        deleteSection: deleteSection,
        moveSection: moveSection,
        getAllSectionLines: getAllSectionLines,

        createBranch: createBranch,
        deleteBranch: deleteBranch,
        moveBranch: moveBranch,
        getAllBranchLines: getAllBranchLines
    });

    // ----
    // PUBLIC
    // ----

    function moveLine(config, from, to)
    {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "server_components/custom_component/ajax/changeLineOrder.php",
            data:
            {
                config: config,
                from: from,
                to: to
            }
        });

        return(request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
    };

    function moveSection(config, from, to)
    {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "server_components/custom_component/ajax/changeSectionOrder.php",
            data:
            {
                config: config,
                from: from,
                to: to
            }
        });

        return(request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
    };

    function moveBranch(config, section, from, to)
    {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "server_components/custom_component/ajax/changeBranchOrder.php",
            data:
            {
                config: config,
                section: section,
                from: from,
                to: to
            }
        });

        return(request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
    };

    function getAllLines(config)
    {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "server_components/custom_component/ajax/getAll.php",
            data:
            {
                config: config
            }
        });

        return(request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
    };

    function getAllLinesGroupedObj(config)
    {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "server_components/custom_component/ajax/getAll2.php",
            data:
            {
                config: config
            }
        });

        return(request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
    };

    function getAllLinesGroupedArr(config)
    {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "server_components/custom_component/ajax/getAll2Arr.php",
            data:
            {
                config: config
            }
        });

        return(request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
    };

    function getAllBranchLines(config, section)
    {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "server_components/custom_component/ajax/getAllBranches.php",
            data:
            {
                config: config,
                section: section
            }
        });

        return(request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
    };

    function getAllSectionLines(config)
    {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "server_components/custom_component/ajax/getAllSections.php",
            data:
            {
                config: config
            }
        });

        return(request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
    };

    function deleteSection(config, section)
    {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "server_components/custom_component/ajax/removeSection.php",
            data:
            {
                config: config,
                it: section
            }
        });

        return(request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
    };

    function createSection(config, section)
    {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "server_components/custom_component/ajax/createSection.php",
            data:
            {
                config: config,
                it: section
            }
        });

        return(request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
    };

    function deleteBranch(config, section, branch)
    {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "server_components/custom_component/ajax/removeBranch.php",
            data:
            {
                config: config,
                section: section,
                it: branch
            }
        });

        return(request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
    };

    function createBranch(config, section, branch)
    {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "server_components/custom_component/ajax/createBranch.php",
            data:
            {
                config: config,
                section: section,
                it: branch
            }
        });

        return(request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
    };

    // ----
    // PRIVATE
    // ----

    function handleError(response)
    {
        if(
            !angular.isObject(response.data) ||
            !response.data.message
        )
        {
            return($q.reject(response.data.message));
        }

        return(response.data);
    };

    function handleSuccess(response)
    {
        return(response.data);
    };

 });

appModule.controller('MasterCtrl', function($scope, confService)
{
    $scope.sections = [];
    loadSections();

    // ----
    // PRIVATE
    // ----

    function loadSections()
    {
        confService.getAllSectionLines().then(function(_sections)
        {
            applySections(_sections);
        });
    };

    function applySections(_sections)
    {
        $scope.sections = _sections;
    };
});

appModule.controller('SectionCtrl', function($scope, confService)
{
    $scope.branches = [];

    $scope.loadBranches = function(sectionName)
    {
        confService.getAllBranchLines("extensions", sectionName).then(function(_branches)
        {
            $scope.applyBranches(_branches);
        });
    }

    $scope.applyBranches = function(_branches)
    {
        $scope.branches = _branches;
    }
});

appModule.controller('BranchCtrl', function($scope)
{

});

appModule.controller('NavCtrl', function($scope)
{
    $scope.msg = "Construction";
});
```

Unfortunately there is no live demo, this is corporate code and this was all I was authorized to release for help, however if you need any additional information please ask as I may be able to share it. Like I said any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've narrowed down the error appears to be happening in

1. $scope.loadBranches = function(sectionName)
2. {
3. *confService.getAllBranchLines("extensions", **sectionName**).then(function(_branches)*
4. {
5. $scope.applyBranches(_branches);
6. });
7. }

But I could be wrong and if I am correct I cant figure out how to fix it

**EDIT: ** Live demo here `http://107.170.154.154`

Comment: There is a lot of code to review here and very few specifics about the problem. The best way forward, if you'd like to receive some help, would be for you to create a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) which replicates the issues without divulging any corporate secrets. I'm often surprised at how easy it can be to take a domain specific problem and demonstrate it generically.

Comment: Heres a live demo with private info stripped out http://107.170.154.154

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ng-repeat` relies on a scope function which returns a new array every time it runs. Even if the returned value is equivalent each time internally, it is still a different object (ie the function is not idempotent). This causes another $digest cycle to run, which returns another value, which causes it to run again, and so on. Left unchecked, it would go on forever. This is why you see the error.

This line of your code is your problem:

```
{{loadBranches(section.sectionName)}}
```

... in tandem with the accompanying controller code.

The solution is to instead initialize `$scope.branches`:

**SectionCtrl:**

```
appModule.controller('SectionCtrl', function($scope, confService) {
    confService.getAllBranchLines("extensions", $scope.section.sectionName).then(function(_branches)
    {
         $scope.branches = _branches;
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

{{section.sectionName}}

```
<ul class="list-group branch-list">
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" ng-repeat="branch in branches"
    ng-controller="BranchCtrl">
        {{branch.rawLine}}&nbsp;
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bzMX7XnKoKr52Fy9vK8r?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, that fixes it, I also had some weird post issue afterwards where PHP wasnt picking up the values being sent in the "data" section and despite it listening on the $_REQUEST variable so I switched to GET and "params" - now everything works great, thanks, what was the issue so I dont make this mistake again